# Django json strategy?

Tags: django, json, caching

I am using wunderground's json api to query for weather conditions on my site. The api gives me a nice json object with all the neccesary data, but I am limited to a number of calls per day. What would be the preferred way to store this data?

I was thinking to dump the json to a file, and check for it's timestamp: if it's say older than 60 minutes, then fetch the new one and overwrite, if it  is not, read the file from the disk. I wouldn't create a database table just to store weather data that I don't essentially need. Is there some clever Django way of caching this process or should I do it manually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Django has a built in caching mechanism. If you don't want to install a caching server, you could use the file system cache, which would be pretty much the same as what you're talking about, but you wouldn't have to roll it yourself.

[Here's the documentation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#filesystem-caching)

You would put something like this in your settings.py

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
        'LOCATION': '/var/tmp/django_cache',
    }
}
```

In your app code, you could then have some logic to check the cache, and if it isn't found, then load it from the server and cache it.

```
from django.core.cache import cache

weather_json_data = cache.get('weather_90210'):
if not weather_json_data:
    weather_json_data = get_data_from_api(zip)

    cache.set('weather_{0}'.format(zip), weather_json_data, 60)

#return the weather_json_data through HttpResponse here
```